# Threats found in /dev/fd

Tags: osx, malware

While trying to make sure I have no threats on my iMac I used Bitdefender to perform a full scan and I found this

[image]

Output of running `ls -la` in `/dev/fd`:

```
 ls -la
total 11
dr-xr-xr-x  1 root         wheel         0 Nov 25 16:43 .
dr-xr-xr-x  3 root         wheel      5426 Nov 25 16:43 ..
crw---w---  1 ahmedyounes  tty     16,   1 Nov 26 03:42 0
crw---w---  1 ahmedyounes  tty     16,   1 Nov 26 03:42 1
crw---w---  1 ahmedyounes  tty     16,   1 Nov 26 03:42 2
dr--r--r--  1 root         wheel         0 Nov 25 16:43 3
dr--r--r--  1 root         wheel         0 Nov 25 16:43 4
dr--r--r--  1 root         wheel         0 Nov 25 16:43 5
```

How can I clear this threat even its just .exe keygen?
What it may be the source of this threat?

**Update after solving it thanks to Scott , duskwuff and JigglyNaga**

it was strange that I couldn't delete it from my iMac until I went to Gmail from the website and found it.

[image]

Comment: Repeating the question from [Scott's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/484128/90751): Is this system a mailserver?  Is it used for email at all?  The locations shown suggest that there are hundreds of thousands of messages, some of which are nearly a decade old.

Comment: I have installed Thunderbird to download Gmail on my iMac, so I got all my old emails which there was keygen in some attachments as mentioned but I came to know that its just strings.
I made a search on my web Gmail for such emails and nothing found.

Comment: What do you mean by "came to know that its just strings", and why do you think that makes it ignorable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. I wouldn't say that this should be disregarded,
   but I agree with [duskwuff](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/484115/23408#484116) that
   *the **presentation** of* the message is nonsense. 
   And I agree that, even if Bitdefender found something in `/dev/fd/9`,
   it was specific and localized to a process that was running at that instant,
   and you won't find anything in `/dev/fd` now. 
   I suggest that you

   - research "Salfeld.Child.Control", "BRD\BRD\keygen\Keygen.exe",
     and other strings from the messages, and
   - get another anti-virus product.
2. The Bitdefender screen talks about "messages" and "Subject" lines. 
   Do you have email on your system? 
   Is there a message with Subject "child control"? 
   The problem might be there. 
   Be careful; if the message has attachments, **do not open them**.
3. Your question title is wrong;
   there's nothing in your question about "tty". 
   The problem was reported in fd 9;
   the only ttys in your questions are file descriptors 0, 1 and 2.

Comment: Re. 1: `/dev/fd` is specifically the file descriptors **of the current process**. Which, for Bitdefender, is Bitdefender itself. If it "found" something in there, it may be a false positive from its own virus description files.

Comment: @duskwuff: Duh. Good point. I totally overlooked that.

Comment: @duskwuff -- AV products have ways to avoid detecting their own description files (although they occasionally detect each other's). The process' "own descriptor" is likely to point to a temporary file that Bitdefender creates while scanning a mailbox.  Two emails had that rar attachment, which includes an (alleged) [keygen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keygen) for [Salfeld Child Control](https://salfeld.com/en/software/parental-control/); that executable is what BitDefender believes to be malware.

Answer (score 4):

This result is nonsense, and should be disregarded. There is something seriously wrong with this antivirus software.

The objects in `/dev/fd` on macOS are not files -- they represent the file descriptors which the current process has open. It makes no sense to "scan" a file descriptor for viruses, and makes even less sense to attempt to "quarantine" one.

Comment: is there a way to delete/unlink/close this file descriptor? https://linux.die.net/man/2/close

Comment: No. The objects in that directory are not the same for every process, and are not permanently stored anywhere.

Comment: so it's just strings ?! "keygen.exe"

Answer (score 2):

You downloaded your email archive, and the virus scanner scanned it and found malware inside some attachments.

Two emails had an attachment named `Salfeld.Child.Control.2008.v9.975.0.0.rar`, and inside that Rar archive there was a file named "Keygen.exe".  The full directory name `Salfeld.Child.Control.2008.v9.975.0.0.WinALL.Incl.Keygen-BRD` *suggests* that this archive contained both [Salfeld's "Child Control" product](https://salfeld.com/en/software/parental-control/), and a [key generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keygen) for it; the virus scanner believes that the "keygen" executable is actually malicious.

Now, for one reason or another, the virus scanner wasn't able to show you an absolute path to the file(s) in which it found a detection.  This may have been because it was scanning the emails mid-download, before saving to disk; or it may have been because it was scanning an archive containing 10 years' worth of emails, and needed to (temporarily) extract them somewhere.

Either way, its fallback was to report the meaningless `/dev/fd/<number>` (which was only a valid file handle for the scanner process), followed by some more helpful details: email subject and date, the attachment name, and the filename within the Rar archive.

If you were to find that email, save the ".rar" attachment to disk and rescan it, or even extract the Rar and scan "keygen.exe" on its own, I expect you would see the same result: "Worm.generic.269236".  **If you don't understand what's happening here, I strongly recommend that you don't extract the archive, even on a Mac**.  Instead, if you have any doubts about this detection being correct (eg. you think the file really is a key generator and nothing more), you should contact the antivirus support directly.

(Full disclosure: I work for another antivirus company.)